# TF2 - GradientTape vs Model.fit() - Why does GradientTape doesn't work?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, gradienttape

Good Evening,

I want to implement a toy example for a simple regression problem with tf2 and the Gradient Tape function. With Model.fit it learns properly but the same with the GradientTape does something but the loss doesn't move compared to model.fit(). Here my example codes and the results. I can't find the problem.

```
model_opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam() 
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y = model(X, training=True)
    loss_value = loss_fn(y_true, y)
grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
model_opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

#Results:
42.47433806265809
42.63973672226078
36.687397360178586
38.744844324717526
36.59080452300609
...
```

Here the Regular case with model.fit()

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),loss=tf.keras.losses.MSE,metrics="mse")
...
model.fit(X,y_true,verbose=0)
#Results
[40.97759069299212]
[28.04145720307729]
[17.643483147375473]
[7.575242056454791]
[5.83682193867299]
```

The accuracy should be roughly the same but it looks like it doesn't learn at all. The input X is a tensor and y_true as well.

***Edit*** for testing

```
import pathlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

dataset_path = keras.utils.get_file("auto-mpg.data", "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data")

column_names = ['MPG','Cylinders','Displacement','Horsepower','Weight',
                'Acceleration', 'Model Year', 'Origin']
dataset = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, names=column_names,
                      na_values = "?", comment='\t',
                      sep=" ", skipinitialspace=True)

dataset = dataset.dropna()
dataset['Origin'] = dataset['Origin'].map({1: 'USA', 2: 'Europe', 3: 'Japan'})
dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset, prefix='', prefix_sep='')

train_dataset = dataset.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=0)
test_dataset = dataset.drop(train_dataset.index)

train_stats = train_dataset.describe()
train_stats.pop("MPG")
train_stats = train_stats.transpose()

train_labels = train_dataset.pop('MPG')
test_labels = test_dataset.pop('MPG')

def norm(x):
  return (x - train_stats['mean']) / train_stats['std']

normed_train_data = norm(train_dataset)
normed_test_data = norm(test_dataset)

def build_model_fit():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)])
  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
  model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=optimizer)
  return model

def build_model_tape():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)])
  opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
  return model, opt

model_f = build_model_fit()
model_g, opt_g = build_model_tape()

EPOCHS = 20

#Model.fit() - Test
history = model_f.fit(normed_train_data, train_labels, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=2)

X = tf.convert_to_tensor(normed_train_data.to_numpy())
y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_labels.to_numpy())

#GradientTape - Test
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
for i in range(0,EPOCHS):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y = model_g(X, training=True)
        loss_value = loss_fn(y_true, y)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model_g.trainable_variables)
    opt_g.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model_g.trainable_variables))
    print(loss_value)
```

Comment: You should not be passing in the trainable weights to the loss function. You should use `loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MSE()` and then `loss_value = loss_fn(y_true, y)`. Note the parens to instantiate the `MSE` object.

Comment: @jakub I switched `model.trainable_weights` to `model.trainable_variables`. The loss function can't be initiated without directly using MSE(y_true,y). I switched it now to `loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()`. It still does not work. This is really frustrating.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize `tf.keras.losses.MSE` was a function, not a class. Can you please post a complete, minimal, reproducible example of your code? Something that others can run without having to change anything.

Comment: @jakub no problem. I appreciate your help! I added an example with the logical regression example of tensorflow. Just copy paste it. The problem still exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The discrepancy OP sees in loss values is due to using a different batch size in `model.fit` and the `tf.GradientTape` training loop. If the `batch_size` keyword argument to `model.fit` is unspecified, a batch size of 32 will be used. In the `tf.GradientTape` training loop, the batch size is equal to the number of samples in the training set (i.e., 314).

To fix this, implement batching in the training loop. One way to do this is with the `tf.data` API, as shown below.

```py
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
for i in range(0,EPOCHS):
    epoch_losses = []
    for x_batch, y_batch in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y_true)).batch(32):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y = model_g(x_batch, training=True)
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch, y)
            epoch_losses.append(loss_value.numpy())
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model_g.trainable_variables)
        opt_g.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model_g.trainable_variables))
    print(np.mean(loss_value))
```

Also note that `model.fit` shuffles the data with each iteration, whereas the custom training loop does not (that needs to be implemented by the developer).

Comment: OH JESUS! I expected every sort of problem but not that. I thought that ¸`model.fit()` just uses the whole set that i put in if I do not specify it otherwise. thank you for your time and help. Without you I would've needed to use even more hours...I will keep that in mind.